# How to simulate an interrupt storm or a live lock on Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

**Background:**
I am developing a tool which boots up a custom build of Linux and boots into QT based desktop for x86 based machine. My custom Linux runs from USB and when the it boots on a machine with certain brand of sound cards connected, then my tool runs to a live lock situation with a lot of interrupts. I doubt its some problem with APIC driver but the system is renderd useless and I have to poweroff the system.

**My Question:**
I would like to simulate the same situation by using a kernel driver or module. I am not sure if I can cause an interrupt to fire from a module. I have a experience with I2C or SPI which causes interrupts on ARM based Linux boards. But i dont know how to do it from a module

Could anybody please suggest me how to cause an interrupt from a driver?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a module with an interrupt forkbomb in it. Google it. It'll only take a second for your vm to halt.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/interrupts.html